# PHP different select boxes with same options

Tags: php, html, select

I have 4 different select boxes (to select one option from drop down). All of them have same options. For example, Each of the select box has following options, "Div 1", "Div 2", "Div 3", "Div 4".
Suppose, following are 4 values selected in each of the select box.

```
$select1 = 'Div 1'
$select2 = 'Div 4'
$select3 = 'Div 2'
$select4 = 'Div 1'
```

Now, for each of the button, i have a specific 'div id' to display. I am using a simple if statement to check what is value of each select:

```
//show content for button 1:
if ($select1 == 'Div 1'){ ?>
<div id="div1"> .... </div>
<? } else if ($select1 == 'Div 2'){ ?>
<div id="div2"> .... </div>
<? } 
else if ($select1 == 'Div 3'){ ?>
<div id="div3"> .... </div>
<? }
else if ($select1 == 'Div 4'){ ?>
<div id="div4"> .... </div>
<? } ?>
```

I have to repeat the above code for each of the select box, which I am sure, is not a good approach. I am wondering if this process can be done in some shorter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function:

```
function writeDiv($id) {
    switch($id) {
        case 'div1':
            echo '<div id="div1">...';
            break;
        case 'div2':
            echo '<div id="div2">...';
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
writeDiv($select1);
writeDiv($select2);
writeDiv($select3);
writeDiv($select4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your output into an array, then do:

```
<?php echo $arr[$select1]; ?>
```

If this data can't be put into an array, change your else/if statements to a switch and wrap into a function

```
get_html_by_id($id)
{
var $html = "";
    switch($id)
    {
        case "DIV 1":
            $html= "<div 1 />"
            break;
        case "DIV 2":
            $html = "<div 2 />"
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return $html;
}

<?php echo get_html_by_id($select1); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ever thought about using arrays?

```
$selects = array(
    array('tag'=>'Div 1', 'content'=>'...'),
    array('tag'=>'Div 4', 'content'=>'...'),
    array('tag'=>'Div 2', 'content'=>'...'),
    array('tag'=>'Div 1', 'content'=>'...'),
);

foreach ( $selects as $select )
{
    print '<div id="'.$select['tag'].'">'.$select['content'].'</div>';
}
```